# don't startapache2

Tags: server, apache2

```
    ● apache2.service - The Apache HTTP Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2021-09-29 23:11:20 CEST; 8s ago
       Docs: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/
    Process: 2900 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/apachectl start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Sep 16 02:00:05 vps23591424.lowhosting.org systemd[1]: Reloaded The Apache HTTP Server.
Sep 17 02:00:27 vps23591424.lowhosting.org systemd[1]: Reloading The Apache HTTP Server.
Sep 17 02:00:28 vps23591424.lowhosting.org systemd[1]: Reloaded The Apache HTTP Server.
Sep 18 02:00:02 vps23591424.lowhosting.org systemd[1]: Reloading The Apache HTTP Server.
Sep 18 02:00:02 vps23591424.lowhosting.org systemd[1]: Reloaded The Apache HTTP Server.
Sep 19 02:00:03 vps23591424.lowhosting.org systemd[1]: Reloading The Apache HTTP Server.
Sep 19 02:00:03 vps23591424.lowhosting.org systemd[2676178]: apache2.service: Failed to set up mount namespacing: /run/systemd/unit-root/tmp: No such file or directory
Sep 19 02:00:03 vps23591424.lowhosting.org systemd[2676178]: apache2.service: Failed at step NAMESPACE spawning /usr/sbin/apachectl: No such file or directory
Sep 19 02:00:03 vps23591424.lowhosting.org systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=226/NAMESPACE
Sep 19 02:00:03 vps23591424.lowhosting.org systemd[1]: Reload failed for The Apache HTTP Server.
```

Comment: There is not enough information here to even guess at why expected directories do not exist. Could you [edit] your question to include: (1) the exact version of Ubuntu you’re using (2) how you installed Apache server (3) the recent messages in `/var/log/apache2/error.log` (4) whether this is a new install of Apache or one that has worked in the past. With this, it may be possible to offer some suggestions on how to get Apache working.

Comment: don't startapache2 Why should I not start it? That is how the title reads.